# How to get only comma values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a employee table and I am trying to get only comma values in SQL Server.

`Emp` table:

| Eid | Ename |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Peter,J |
| 2 | Mike,S |
| 3 | , |
| 4 | ,,,,,, |

I tried this code:

```
SELECT
    (LEN(ename) - LEN(REPLACE(ename, ',', ''))
FROM emp;
```

I am not getting the length 0 if the values contain only commas.

Expected result: I want only 3 and 4 emp ids.

Comment: `WHERE EName NOT LIKE '%[^ ,]%'`?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: I want only comma values.

Comment: So, just EID 3 then?

Comment: Id 3 and 4.I edited the data

Comment: So `WHERE LEN(Ename) > 0 AND LEN(REPLACE(ename, ',', '')) = 0` ?

Comment: What's the *actual* problem? What you ask is of little use and the solution will be very expensive.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos heh, I'd say the *actual* problem is "putting CSV data in  a column" :)

Comment: @Jard,@Larnu Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select x.eid,x.ename 
from
(
select 1 eid,'Peter,J'  ename union
select 2 eid,'Mike,S' ename union
select 3 eid, ','      ename  union
select 4 eid,',,,,,'  ename 
) x
where len(x.ename)>0 and len( replace(x.ename,',','') ) =0
```

The answer there is condition line "where  ...."

Answer (score 1):

If you're after rows that *only* contain commas you can use some pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT ID, ename
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE EName NOT LIKE '%[^,]%';
```

The pattern will match any characters that *aren't* a comma, and then the `NOT LIKE` effectively reverses that; meaning that only rows that contain commas (or a zero length string) will be returned. If you want to omit zero length strings too, then add an additional clause in the `WHERE` to exclude them.

Answer (score 0):

Please try  the following solution.

SQL #1 is tokenizing the ***ename*** column by using XML/Query.

Predicate `r[text()]` picks up tokens with any value.

SQL #2 is much simpler.

**SQL #1**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, ename VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO @tbl (ename) VALUES
('Peter,J'),
('Mike,S'),
(','),
(', , , ,');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

SELECT * 
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
         REPLACE(REPLACE(ename,SPACE(1),''), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
         ']]></r></root>' AS XML).query('
         for $x in /root/r[text()]
         return $x
         ').value('.','VARCHAR(255)')) AS t1(c)
WHERE c = '';
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------+---+
| ID |  ename  | c |
+----+---------+---+
|  3 |       , |   |
|  4 | , , , , |   |
+----+---------+---+
```

**SQL #2**

```
SELECT * 
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(ename, ',','')) AS t(c)
WHERE c = '';
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------+---+
| ID |  ename  | c |
+----+---------+---+
|  3 |       , |   |
|  4 | , , , , |   |
+----+---------+---+
```

Comment: All SQL Server versions in mainstream support have `STRING_SPLIT`. Even SQL Server 2016 is out of mainstream support now

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, The OP didn't provide a minimal reproducible example. That's why I had to stoop down to earlier versions.

Comment: For 2016 you can use JSON instead of XML, which will be faster. For older versions - we're 8 years back already, the OP should make it clear just how old the server is

Comment: It's reasonable that we should encourage moving away from lowest common denominator solutions..